# How to use UIPath to make a video loop through say 100times?

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-activity

Is there a way to run or loop a video 100 times using UIPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is having a simple **Int32** `Counter`.

Do it with a usual `While` or with a `Do While`. That depends on what you want to achieve.

[image: UiPath process]

If you need to wait a bit between the videos, just add the Delay activity:
[image: Delay activity]